# How to get the table counts for unique values in column

Tags: r

I have this matrix `mymat`. I know I can do `table((mymat[,"col1"])` to get the number of each item in `col1`. However, I only want the count if there are unique values in col2. For `mymat` below, I want this result:

```
app  gg  chh
 1    2   1
```

mymat

```
col1   col2
app    d
app    d
gg     e
gg     f 
gg     e
chh    f
chh    f
chh    f
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `unique` to subset the data (works for `matrix` and `data.frame`) and then call `table`:

`table(unique(mymat)[,1])`

This returns

```
# app chh  gg 
#   1   1   2
```

Comment: Very concise answer. I forgot that `base::unique` has a `data.frame` method

Answer (score 7):

You can use `duplicated` to subset the data and then call `table`:

```
table(subset(df, !duplicated(paste(col1, col2)), select = col1))
#app chh  gg 
#  1   1   2
```

As a second option, here's a dplyr approach:

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df) %>% count(col1)   # or distinct(df, col1, col2) if you have other columns
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#    col1     n
#  (fctr) (int)
#1    app     1
#2    chh     1
#3     gg     2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is counting the nonzeros in table()-result

```
rowSums(table(df$col1, df$col2)!=0)
```

result:

```
app chh  gg 
  1   1   2
```

data used:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"col1   col2
app    d
app    d
gg     e
gg     f 
gg     e
chh    f
chh    f
chh    f")
```

Answer (score 0):

Other suggestions are better, but here I throw another possibility just for diversity:

```
apply(dcast(df, col1 ~ col2)[-1], 1, function(x) {sum(x > 0)})
```